# Why is my length only half of what I want it to be?

Tags: python

I want the length of the pattern to match the length of the data segment, where is this going wrong?

```
data_segment = [] #an empty list

data_series = [-1, 2, -2, 3, 41, 38, 22, 10, -1, 3]
pattern = [40, 30, 20, 10]


out_list = [] #an empty list to contain the final output

length = len(pattern) #length of pattern list


for i, v in enumerate(data_series):
        if i + length > len(data_series) + 2: 
            break

        data_segment.append([v, data_series[i+1]])
print(data_segment)
```

Which prints

```
[[-1, 2], [2, -2], [-2, 3], [3, 41], [41, 38], [38, 22], [22, 10], [10, -1], [-1, 3]]
```

But I need it to print

```
[[-1, 2, -2, 3], [2, -2, 3, 41], [-2, 3, 41, 38], [3, 41, 38, 22], [41, 38, 22, 10], [38, 22, 10, -1], [22, 10, -1, 3]]
```

Comment: Where is `data_segment`? is this the same as `data_series`??

Comment: you're creating lists of 2 elements in your list. How can that become lists of 4 elements?

Comment: sorry, data_segment is a new list

Comment: you need to slice: `data_segment.append(data_series[i:i+4])`

Comment: what's making the list 2 elements only? sorry, very new to python @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 3):

your code

```
data_segment.append([v, data_series[i+1]])
```

is creating a list of 2-element lists. Not what you need from your desired output.

You need to generate a list of overlapping slices of the length of your pattern with some truncation to only generate sublists of the exact pattern length, in one line using list comprehension instead of a loop:

```
data_segment = [data_series[i:i+len(pattern)] for i in range((len(data_series)//4)*4 - 1)]
```

prints:

```
[[-1, 2, -2, 3], [2, -2, 3, 41], [-2, 3, 41, 38], [3, 41, 38, 22], [41, 38, 22, 10], [38, 22, 10, -1], [22, 10, -1, 3]]
```